# How to stack behaviour with traits extending BeforeAfterAll

Tags: specs2

I'm in a situtation where I have 2 traits extending BeforeAfterAll doing different actions for integration tests: One managing the database and the other the file system. For example:

```
trait DBSpecification extends BeforeAfterAll {

  override def beforeAll() = {
    println("DB -> BeforeAll")
  }

  override def afterAll() = {
    println("DB -> AfterAll")
  }
}

trait FileSystemSpecification extends BeforeAfterAll {

  override def beforeAll() = {
    println("FileSystem -> BeforeAll")
  }

  override def afterAll() = {
    println("FileSystem -> AfterAll")
  }
}

class MyTest extends Specification with DBSpecification with FileSystemSpecification {

  "some test" in {
    1 ==== 1
  }

}
```

If I do like this, only the prints of the last trait are executed, in this case FileSystemSpecification. If I try calling `super` from the traits, I start having some compilation problems. I've tried already a bunch of ways, but couldn't figure out the solution.

ScalaTest has some examples on its [documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#composingFixtures.html), but couldn't find a way with Specs2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes traits are not the best thing for composing behaviour. Here is the boilerplaty way to do it:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.specification._

trait DBSpecification extends BeforeAfterAll {

  def beforeAll() = {
    println("DB -> BeforeAll")
  }

  def afterAll() = {
    println("DB -> AfterAll")
  }
}

trait FileSystemSpecification extends BeforeAfterAll {

  def beforeAll() = {
    println("FileSystem -> BeforeAll")
  }

  def afterAll() = {
    println("FileSystem -> AfterAll")
  }
}

trait FileSystemDBSpecification extends DBSpecification with FileSystemSpecification {
  override def beforeAll() = {
    super[DBSpecification].beforeAll()
    super[FileSystemSpecification].beforeAll()
  }

  override def afterAll() = {
    super[DBSpecification].afterAll()
    super[FileSystemSpecification].afterAll()
  }
}

class MyTestSpec extends Specification with FileSystemDBSpecification {

  "some test" in {
    1 ==== 1
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Not that I know of.